# How display a text using silverlight in Windows phone 7

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I need to display a text "welcome" on the right-bottom corner of a canvas with red colour

this is my xaml code

```
  <Canvas x:Name="imageOne" Background="White"  Width="480" Height="800" >
            </Canvas>
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas defines an area within which you have to explicitly position TextBlock element by coordinates relative to the Canvas area. Means you have to do absolute positioning inside a Canvas.

If you really want to use a Canvas, you can better take a transparent Grid inside it and put a TextBlock inside that Grid.

Example:

```
<Canvas x:Name="imageOne" Background="White" Width="480" Height="800">
    <Grid Width="480" Height="800">
        <TextBlock Text="Visifire" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Please make sure that the Grid size is same as Canvas size.